# CommissioningClient.API is not available on this device

Tags: google-smart-home, matter-iot-standard

On running the code provided in code lab in https://developers.home.google.com/codelabs/matter-sample-app#1

I have tried to run it on physical android phone (with compatible android version and google play services version) as well as pixel 6 virtual phone on emulator. In both cases it is showing this error.

````
E/GHSAFM-HomeViewModel: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 17: API: CommissioningClient.API is not available on this device. Connection failed with: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null, message=null}
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.ApiExceptionUtil.fromStatus(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.1.0:3)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.ApiExceptionMapper.getException(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.1.0:1)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zag.zad(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.1.0:1)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zabq.zaE(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.1.0:7)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zabq.zaD(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.1.0:2)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zabq.zar(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.1.0:24)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zabt.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.1.0:12)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)```
````

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for bringing this up. It seems you are missing gms module.
Can you reinstall both Google Play and Google Home apps.
Once reinstalled, enable debugging mode and run the commands below.

adb shell dumpsys package com.google.android.gms | grep "versionName"

adb shell dumpsys activity provider com.google.android.gms.chimera.container.GmsModuleProvider | grep "com.google.android.gms.home"

adb shell dumpsys activity provider com.google.android.gms.chimera.container.GmsModuleProvider | grep "com.google.android.gms.optional_home"

adb shell dumpsys activity provider com.google.android.gms.chimera.container.GmsModuleProvider | grep "com.google.android.gms.policy_home"

adb shell dumpsys activity provider com.google.android.gms.chimera.container.GmsModuleProvider | grep "com.google.android.gms.threadnetwork"

adb shell dumpsys package com.google.android.apps.chromecast.app | grep versionName

adb shell dumpsys activity provider com.google.android.gms.chimera.container.GmsModuleProvider | grep "Enabled features" | grep -i "home"

adb shell getprop ro.build.version.release

adb shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk

If you have versions < prefixes 23.05 / 2305, please ensure the home app and play services are up to date and check later again. If you have versions >= 2305 and still experiencing the issue, please open a ticket in [Public issue tracker.](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=655104&template=1284148)